# Org Babel: Open Python shell on session?

Tags: org-babel, python

When I run an Org Babel shell code block with e.g. `:session a` header argument, it automatically opens a buffer `a` with the shell for this session, so I can explore it interactively.

I love this feature! Is it possible to get the same behavior with Python blocks as well? It doesn't seem to happen automatically for me.

Comment: I think it should work the same, except that in the python case, the buffer name gets 'earmuffs', so that e.g. `session: b` creates a comint buffer named `*b*.

Comment: Unclear what happened with the edit request, but if you're asking to delete the question, please do so from the OP's account rather than a differently named account.